# react-native bundle throws SyntaxError in dev and prod mode

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native to bundle an Android APK. 
I am able to run it properly in dev mode but have not been able to release a signed apk yet.

`` node version: `v5.10.0`
npm version: `3.8.3`
react-native version: `0.22.2` ``

Tried with babel-core versions
`6.5.1`
`6.4.5`
`6.7.4`

The error I am getting on running either of these commands
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

is

> ```
> bundle: Created ReactPackager
> uncaught error Error: SyntaxError: /Users/'username'/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:
> ```
>
> Unexpected token (120:2)
>         // Note: this must be placed last to prevent eager
>         // evaluation of the getter-wrapped submodules above
>         ...require('React'),
>       };
>
> ```
> if (__DEV__) {
>     at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
>     at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2817:8)
>     at Parser.pp.parseIdentifier (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1227:10)
>     at Parser.pp.parsePropertyName (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1070:135)
>     at Parser.pp.parseObj (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:986:12)
>     at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:718:19)
>     at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:4305:22)
>     at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:504:19)
>     at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:484:19)
>     at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/babylon/index.js:415:19)
> See logs /var/folders/zj/sk4075x566l8jdl1gwzjl79h0000gn/T/react-packager.log
>     at SocketClient._handleMessage (SocketClient.js:144:23)
>     at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (SocketClient.js:53:42)
>     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
>     at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:182:7)
>     at BunserBuf.process (/Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/bser/index.js:289:10)
>     at /Users/mihir/projects/personal/openchs/openchs-client/node_modules/bser/index.js:244:12
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
> ```

More of my code is here - https://github.com/OpenCHS/openchs-client

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that finds this and is looking for the answer, it can be found here: [SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424631/syntaxerror-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module-1/41472361#41472361)

you will need to install babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 package and include it in your .babelrc presets array